# file_validators gem works for sound but not images

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, image-uploading

I started using the file_validators gem to limit upload size in my rails 4 project (I'm using carrierwave). In my model I currently have:

```
validates :image, presence: true, file_size: { less_than: 8.megabytes }
validates :sound, presence: true, file_size: { less_than_or_equal_to: 100.kilobytes }
```

Upon testing, this behaves as expected with sound files (outputs the message if one tries to upload a larger file). However, there is no error message for larger images, which it accepts. I have tried restarting the server and signing in and out of my project, but no jive. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate file size, I think you should do it client-side on the browser. Otherwise, I believe the whole file gets uploaded, evaluated according to your rules before being rejected.